# Android : Notification Manager only notify when the application is closed

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

1. I implemented a Broadcast Receiver, at OnReceive() method Notification Manager Code is written.
2. Custom Ringtone is being played at Notification. On click of Notification the sound stops

**Issues**
I am failed to do, ***If Application is Open than the Notification won't be showed at notification bar.*** expect of notification i will Update UI of my View[i.e. i will show STOP button to stop the ringtone.]

**NOTIFICATION CODE**

```
public void sendNotification(Context context, String title, String message, String fileName)
    {
            final String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
            final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(ns);
            final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, context.getString(R.string.SalahClock),  System.currentTimeMillis());

            Intent intent = new Intent( context, Main.class);
            intent.putExtra("isAlarmPlaying", true);

            //Pending event to open our Application Screen when this notification is clicked
            final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent , 0);

            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
            notification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://path.."); 
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
            notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
```

**On ReCevie**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

serviceHandler = new Handler(context);
         PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
         PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Salah");
         wl.acquire();

         serviceHandler.sendNotification(context, "", "", "");

         wl.release();

    }
```

Thanks,
Salik

Comment: I didn't understand if your question is: "this is what happens, how to fix this", or "this is what I want, how to do it?"

Comment: Notification Also opens when the Application is active [or opened]. Notification should only show when the Application is closed.

Comment: If you have a better solution, please post it below and accept your own solution. And if my answer is best, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a static variable:

```
public static boolean sIsActive = false;
```

anywhere in you project, and set it to `true` on you activity `onResume()` and to `false` on your activity `onPause()`.

Than in your receiver you can check:

```
if (MyClass.sIsActive) { return; }
```

and if not active, continue with your notification.

Comment: Thanks, but seeking for better way

Comment: It is a good and simple way to do what you want, and it works. Can you write what is missing from this solution?